# What is a good metric to compare matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a matrix that I obtained from theoretical computation and I have another matrix which I obtained by actual data collection. How do I compare the two matrices? How do I state that one matrix is significantly different from the other?

I have looked into:

- Frobenius Norm but I don't know what should be my threshold for comparison.
- Looking at max and min deviation of one matrix from the other. But again, what's a good threshold?

I thought that to say one matrix varies significantly from the other, I would need to quantify the variance of those terms and compare how the deviation compares to the variance (or SD) but sadly, I don't have data for that and neither can I theoretically estimate any variances.

I am kind of lost in what would be a good metric.

Comment: This depends entirely on your application. Different metrics will be appropriate for different purposes.

Comment: Mathematical Statistics.

Comment: How was the matrix constructed and what do its entries represent?

Comment: @FlybyNight. The theoretical matrix is constructed using regression and the obtained matrix is well, obtained.

Comment: In that case, the metric will be constructed using metric theory and it's details will be found, somehow.